# lognormal distribution average and variance

Tags: lognormal-distribution, scipy

I am trying to get acquainted with this type of distribution, and part of it is exploring what random number generation with `scipy.stats` produces. I have noticed that if I produce a `normal` distribution and then calculate average and std on the obtained array, the agreement with the imposed parameters is good already for a relatively small number of samples:

```
import scipy.stats as st
import numpy as np

d3 = st.norm.rvs(1,0.2,size=1000)
print(d3.mean())
print(d3.std())

0.996408828534
0.205429513285
```

I am not sure I can say the same for a `lognormal` distribution:

```
s = 1.2
d1 = st.lognorm.rvs(s, size=3000)
d2 = st.lognorm.rvs(s, size=30000)

d1.std()**2
9.3344792142262989

d2.std()**2
12.281877945365549
```

whereas from the definition ($\mu = \ln(scale) = 0$)

```
(np.exp(s**2)-1)*np.exp(s**2)
13.593577362615642
```

(**Note**: the parameter `s` is equivalent to $\sigma$ in `scipy`, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28700694/log-normal-random-variables-with-scipy?lq=1) to very good description)

I wonder why the variance appears to be so sensitive on the number of samples, and in general not very close to its theoretical value. Is it something peculiar to this kind of distribution and the way random numbers are generated, or am I missing something?

**EDIT** : following a suggestion by @gung, running few tests iteratively confirms 'instability' of the variance, as explained by @hodgenovice:

```
s = 1.2
for i in range(10):
    d1 = st.lognorm.rvs(s, size=3000)
    d2 = st.lognorm.rvs(s, size=30000)
    lgn_th_mean = np.exp(s**2/2)
    lgn_th_var = (np.exp(s**2)-1)*np.exp(s**2)
    print('d1 stats: mean = {:.3f}, var = {:.3f}, expected mean: {:.3f}, expected var: {:.3f}, mean of log: {:.3f}, var of log: {:.3f}'\
          .format(d1.mean(),d1.std()**2,lgn_th_mean,lgn_th_var,np.log(d1).mean(),np.log(d1).std()**2))
    print('d2 stats: mean = {:.3f}, var = {:.3f}, expected mean: {:.3f}, expected var: {:.3f}, mean of log: {:.3f}, var of log: {:.3f}'\
          .format(d2.mean(),d2.std()**2,lgn_th_mean,lgn_th_var,np.log(d2).mean(),np.log(d2).std()**2))

d1 stats: mean = 2.001, var = 12.595, expected mean: 2.054, expected var: 13.594, mean of log: -0.048, var of log: 1.493
d2 stats: mean = 2.041, var = 11.798, expected mean: 2.054, expected var: 13.594, mean of log: 0.010, var of log: 1.419
d1 stats: mean = 1.912, var = 10.081, expected mean: 2.054, expected var: 13.594, mean of log: -0.037, var of log: 1.379
d2 stats: mean = 2.064, var = 13.583, expected mean: 2.054, expected var: 13.594, mean of log: 0.007, var of log: 1.431
d1 stats: mean = 2.125, var = 12.299, expected mean: 2.054, expected var: 13.594, mean of log: 0.014, var of log: 1.511
d2 stats: mean = 2.047, var = 12.364, expected mean: 2.054, expected var: 13.594, mean of log: 0.001, var of log: 1.443
d1 stats: mean = 2.057, var = 13.110, expected mean: 2.054, expected var: 13.594, mean of log: 0.016, var of log: 1.384
d2 stats: mean = 2.061, var = 20.173, expected mean: 2.054, expected var: 13.594, mean of log: -0.008, var of log: 1.443
d1 stats: mean = 2.129, var = 14.420, expected mean: 2.054, expected var: 13.594, mean of log: 0.038, var of log: 1.429
d2 stats: mean = 2.021, var = 11.572, expected mean: 2.054, expected var: 13.594, mean of log: -0.007, var of log: 1.435
d1 stats: mean = 2.046, var = 15.501, expected mean: 2.054, expected var: 13.594, mean of log: -0.002, var of log: 1.393
d2 stats: mean = 2.050, var = 14.722, expected mean: 2.054, expected var: 13.594, mean of log: -0.006, var of log: 1.444
d1 stats: mean = 2.069, var = 16.008, expected mean: 2.054, expected var: 13.594, mean of log: 0.011, var of log: 1.376
d2 stats: mean = 2.030, var = 19.172, expected mean: 2.054, expected var: 13.594, mean of log: -0.009, var of log: 1.430
d1 stats: mean = 1.966, var = 9.853, expected mean: 2.054, expected var: 13.594, mean of log: -0.009, var of log: 1.412
d2 stats: mean = 2.051, var = 13.964, expected mean: 2.054, expected var: 13.594, mean of log: -0.006, var of log: 1.447
d1 stats: mean = 2.070, var = 15.729, expected mean: 2.054, expected var: 13.594, mean of log: -0.022, var of log: 1.462
d2 stats: mean = 2.073, var = 13.725, expected mean: 2.054, expected var: 13.594, mean of log: 0.005, var of log: 1.447
d1 stats: mean = 2.050, var = 15.448, expected mean: 2.054, expected var: 13.594, mean of log: 0.003, var of log: 1.406
d2 stats: mean = 2.031, var = 12.177, expected mean: 2.054, expected var: 13.594, mean of log: -0.003, var of log: 1.432
```

Comment: How stable would it be if you took the log of the values before calculating the parameters?

Comment: I have included a small set of trials in the question. The effect of the log is to 'calm down' the data, compress them. Sort of the opposite of what the exponential does, which is what @hodgenovice was explaining below.

Answer (score 1):

What you've written looks correct to me.

Here's one way of thinking about why the variance is less stable for the lognormal distribution if we estimate it from some generated random samples:

One way of constructing a random variable with a lognormal distribution is by taking `e` to the power of some random variable with a normal distribution (as you may well know). We could generate 3000 random samples from independent `N(0, 1.2)` random variables (similar to your lognormal example). If we take the absolute value of these samples (to measure their distance from 0), most of the values are < 1.2, with typically 30-50 values is > 2.5 and 0-3 values > 3.5. The median of our sample is ~ 0.8.

If we repeat the above, and take $e^X$ (take the exponent of each sample) to resemble a lognormal distribution, we find that we have a median value of roughly 1, most values are < 2 with 15-25 values > 12 and maybe one or two > 30.

Therefore, the lognormal distribution is more sensitive to outliers since their distance from your 'typical' point becomes much greater. When we calculate the variance of our samples, the number of these outliers, and exactly how large they are has a greater impact for the lognormal distribution.

Comment: Thanks! I think I get it now. I seem to understand that - for a Normal distribution, the sample $\sigma$ has a variance proportional to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}$, where $N$ is the number of samples..Is there a similar result for lognormal distributions, maybe showing that the dependence is 'slower'?

Comment: @MikeAnblips The $1/\sqrt{N}$ factor will remain, but the variance of the variance may be quite large.